# npm version adding during build by vats

Tags: angular, version

Assuming you have an Angular project set up and have installed `npm`, you can create a new version file containing a build timestamp and version of the web app by following these steps:

1. Install `npm-run-all` package as a development dependency.

npm install npm-run-all --save-dev

2. Add a new script in your `package.json` file that will run two scripts in parallel: one to generate the version file and another to build the Angular app.

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "npm-run-all generate-version build-app",
  "generate-version": "echo \"export const VERSION = {\\\"version\\\": \\\"$(git describe --tags --always --dirty)\\\", \\\"timestamp\\\": \\\"$(date -u +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')\\\"};\" > src/version.ts",
  "build-app": "ng build --prod"
}
```

3. In the above script, the `generate-version` script will create a new `version.ts` file in the `src` folder with the version and timestamp information. The `build-app` script will build the Angular app in production mode. The `build` script will run both scripts in parallel.
4. You can now run the `npm run build` command in your terminal to generate the version file and build the Angular app. The output files will be in the `dist` folder.

Note: The `git describe --tags --always --dirty` command will generate a unique version string based on the latest Git tag, number of commits since the tag, and whether there are uncommitted changes. You can modify this command to generate the version string according to your requirements.

nononononononononononon